# Where is Clipboard Ring in Visual Studio 2022? CTRL + Shift + V opens Code Definition Window

Tags: visual-studio-2022

Just installed VS2022 for C++ development. Added and copied some code using Ctrl+C as usual and then I wanted to try the Clipboard Ring / History feature, which is supposed to appear when pressing Ctrl+Shift+V, but that command only opens the Code Definition Window instead.

How do I get to the Clipboard Ring?
I'm using VS 2022 17.3.6

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I solved it: Ctrl + Shift + Insert